# How to sort a hash in redis by its value

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, redis, node-redis

I'm new to this redis, so please help me!
I'm storing has values in redis by using this command,

```
client.hmset('top_trend', array[0], 0);
client.expire('top_trend', 86400, redis.print);
```

and i'will increment the value "0" if i try to set same key again by using this command,

```
if(client.hexists('top_trend', array[0]) == true){
   client.hincrby('top_trend', array[0] , 1, redis.print);
}
```

This will store my array of data in redis like, 
eg: key = "top_trend"

```
"tamil"
"0"
"english"
"0"
"hindi"
"0"
```

if tamil is already available for the key "top_trend" it will increment its value like this:

```
"tamil"
"1"
"english" (//if english is already 3 times available)
"4"
```

Now i need to sort the values:
in descending order and to get the values in sorted order in node js. How to achieve it.?? I tried sort key_value by object_*->object command like this. But it won't works. help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question - Redis doesn't provide a way to retrieve the contents of a Hash ordered by value. What you can do, providing that the Hash is small-ish, is to fetch it in its entirety and then sort it in the application (Node.js).

Also FYI, it appears that your code is somewhat superfluous - [`HINCRBY`](https://redis.io/commands/hincrby) will initialize the field even if it does not exist, so:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> EXISTS foo
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> HINCRBY foo bar 1
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL foo
1) "bar"
2) "1"
```

That means that unless you have a good reason to initialize and check for existence "manually", you can simply remove that code.

Answer (score 0):

If ordering by some value is a feature you need for your implementation, you may think about having a separate Redis key doing that. You can easily use Sorted Sets for that, by incrementing score with `ZINCRBY`. Furtermore, this way you can also leverage the lexicographical ordering of the stored values.